# select using wildcard to find ending in two character then numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server, wildcard

I am querying to find things ending in "ST" followed by a number 1 - 999.

`SELECT NUMBER WHERE NUMBER LIKE '%ST`  -- works correctly to return everything ending in "ST"

`SELECT NUMBER WHERE NUMBER LIKE '%[1-999]`  -- works correctly to return everything ending in 1 - 999

`SELECT NUMBER WHERE NUMBER LIKE '%ST[1-999]`  -- doesn't work - returns nothing

Also tried:
`SELECT NUMBER WHERE NUMBER LIKE '%ST%[1-999]` -- works, but also returns things like "GRASTNT3" that have extra things between the "ST" and the number

Can anyone help this struggling beginner?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if it works, but have you tried 
`SELECT NUMBER WHERE NUMBER LIKE '%ST' AND NUMBER LIKE '%[1-999]'`
?

Comment: Guga, that returned nothing which kind of makes sense. Thanks for trying!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that [1-999] doesn't mean what you think it does.

SQL Server interprets that as a set of values (1-9, 9, 9) which basically means that if there's more than 1 digit after the ST, the entry won't be returned.

So far as I can tell, your best bet is:

```
SELECT NUMBER WHERE
    NUMBER LIKE '%ST[1-9][0-9][0-9]' OR 
    NUMBER LIKE '%ST[1-9][0-9]' OR 
    NUMBER LIKE '%ST[1-9]'
```

(assuming that your numbers don't have leading zeros - if they do, replace the ones with more zeros)

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks so much for the answer and for also explaining why my way wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do

```
SELECT NUMBER WHERE
    NUMBER LIKE '%ST[1-9][0-9][0-9]'
    OR NUMBER LIKE '%ST[1-9][0-9]'
    OR NUMBER LIKE '%ST[1-9]';
```

The group in the the `[]` is a `Char`/`NChar` not an `Int`.

---

Better still normalise and type your data, so you have an ST `bit` and an `int` column for the number.

If you find you need to define different filters on variable string data, consider [Full Text Searching](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx) or another Lucene related technology depending on your RDBMS.